# How do you move Quiet to a different position

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Quiet does not seem to follow me like other buddies, is there a command to move her ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the iDroid map screen, pressing up or down will scroll through available commands. One of which you can select Quiet's sniping point, and another will let you select a location to scout.

Comment: Oh, nice! I'm going to have to try this out, as it sounds far more accessible than my method.

Comment: @Jeeva: There's a lot of useful commands hidden away in that menu. Like deploying helicopters for example. Too bad it isn't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I've also been having this issue - the trick is that you essentially have to redeploy her from the Buddy Support screen. This is found in the iDroid -> Missions -> Buddy Support.

[image: Buddy Support Screen, Metal Gear Solid V]

When on the Support screen, you can select either of `Quiet (Scout)` and `Quiet (Attack)`, which will relocate Quiet to a specific location, which you then select on the map.